# How to set the following Mongo document structure?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to set up a commenting system using the example on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/storing-comments/

However I am confused on the discussion_id. How do I set that in PHP? Is that a datatype?

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    discussion_id: ObjectId(...),
    slug: '34db',
    posted: ISODateTime(...),
    author: {
              id: ObjectId(...),
              name: 'Rick'
             },
    text: 'This is so bogus ... '
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adance on the answers, MongoDB will not set the `discussion_id` for you. It has no relational behaviour at all as such it cannot anticipate your internal relations between certain objects.

You will need to assign the `discussion_id` yourself from PHP using the `_id` of the discussion row like so:

```
$dis = $db->discussion->findOne(array('name' => 'my awesome new one'));
$db->comments->insert(array('discussion_id' => $dis['_id'], 'text' => 'trololol'));
```

So you need to remember that MongoDB cannot judge any relations and will not however this discussion_id does not have to be set after the document is created as shown above since the `MongoId` object can be called at any time and you can actually override the `_id` on insert into MongoDB. This is particularly useful if you want to form the objects first, check their integrity and then save them.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion_id is of type [ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs).  It contains, in this example, the _id of the parent discussion document.

When the discussion document is created, it will be assigned an _id by mongodb. You can use this value when creating the document for each comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ObjectID's are a BSON datatype. Learn more here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Would need to know more about what languages and technologies you are using to really tell you "how to set that".